# How to insert JSON object in mysql having JSON field type using nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to insert a json object using nodejs [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) module

Here is the query :

```
var ins_sql = "INSERT INTO mapping_master (mapping_name,mapping_json,source_type) VALUES ?";   // mapping_json is of JSON data type

var postData = req.body; // post data is a json

// also tried passing JSON.stringify(postData) instead of postData below
var values = ['map1', postData, 'textFile']; 

db.getConnection(function(err, conn){
    conn.query(ins_sql, [values], function(err)){
      if(err) throw err;
    }
})
```

However, I am getting ER_PARSE_ERROR error: 1064 sqlstate: 42000

Could you please help me with how to insert data containing JSON data type ?

Answer (score 0):

1064 means you have a Syntax error or access violation.

I guess it is a syntax error, 
In insert statement, you must have
VALUES ('value1','Value2')

I doubt a ? can replace all your values.

Try this syntax:

VALUES (?,?,?);

and just pass an array of data  (postData).